# How can I make a <a> tag close a diiv.

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

On my ongoing search for knowledged I yet again reached a wall I am having rouble climbing.Basically I have this div acting as a popUp and I need it to do a couple of things that were working! But then I decided to chnage the close button for a X in the corner to emulate the way a browser´s works.

When I did so I got the following troubles:

1.Div opens but doesn´t close.
2.Button inside the divs doesn´t work, meaning it doesnt open the other popUp with a confirmation.

I also deleated the Js code for the second point because it was giviing me a headache.
Here is the HTML

```
<div class = "popUp" id="popUp">

        <a value="cerrar" id="btnCerrar">X</a>
            <ul>
              <li>Name: Item #1</li>
              <li>BLA/li>
              <li>BLA</li>
              <li>BLAr</li>
            </ul>

        <form class="display" name="opciones" method="get">
            <input type="submit" value="Modificar" id="btnModificar" />

            <input type="submit" value="Eliminar" id="btnEliminar" />
        </form>

    </div>


    <div class = "popUp" id="popUp">

        <a value="cerrar" id="btnCerrar">x</a>
            <p>Ypu sure, it will be deleted for good?</p>
            <p>Delete?.</p>

        <form name="modificar" method="get">
            <input type="submit" value="Borrar" id="btnBorrar" />
        </form>

    </div>
```

Here goes the CSS just in case.

```
.popUp{
border-style: groove; border-width: 2px;
border-color: #2c3e50;
position: absolute;
width:256px;
height: 256px;
background-color: #ecf0f1;
top: 200px;
left: 600px;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
 }

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.display{
display: inline;

}

#btnCerrar{
float: right;
}

#btnEliminar{
float: right;
}
```

And last but not least the JS.

```
    window.onload = function(){

     var elementPopUp = document.getElementById('lnkInfo');

      elementPopUp.addEventListener('click',validate);

      function validate() {
      document.getElementById('popUp').className +=' show';
    }

};




var elementBotonCerrar = document.getElementById('btnCerrar');

elementBotonIngresar.addEventListener('click',validar);

function validar(){

    if(elementBotonCerrar === 'click'){
     document.getElementById('popUp').className +=' hide';
 }

    };
```

Thanks a lot in advance.
Best Wishes

Comment: Try removing the show class along with adding the hide class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following and it worked:

```
var elementInfo = document.getElementById('lnkInfo'),
elementBtnCerrar = document.getElementById('btnCerrar'); 

elementoVerInfo.addEventListener('click', function () {
displayPopUp('popUpCorrect');
});

elementoBotonCerrar.addEventListener('click', function () {
hidePopUp('popUpCorrect');
});

function displayPopUp(pIdDivToShow){
var fElementDivToShow = document.getElementById(pIdDivToShow),
newClass ='';
newClass = fElementDivToShow.className.replace('hide','');
fElementDivToShow.className = newClass + ' show';
}

function hidePopUp(pIdDivToShow){
var fElementDivToShow = document.getElementById(pIdDivToShow),
newClass ='';
newClass = fElementDivToShow.className.replace('show','');
fElementDivToShow.className = newClass + ' hide';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code.

You call a variable to get the "btnCerrer" element but in the next line you attach the event to a different element `elementBotonIngresar`.

Next, in the `validar` function, you ask if the DOM element equals 'click'.

The function should be something like this

```
function validar(e) {
    if(elementBotonCerrar === e.currentTarget) {
        //...
    } 
}
```

Third, you need to **replace** the class name, not add the previous class.

Fourth, unlike classes, element's id should be unique.